# ValueBox in R - Only number is shown

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a shiny dashboard and I want to implement a valueBox within the Dashboard.

```
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    valueBox(totalSales,"Total Sales",color="blue")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("salesTable")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("top10Sales")
  )

)
```

And this is the result: 
The number on the upper left is the variable totalSales but it isn't formatted in a valueBox.

[image: Output with valueBox]

Does anyone know what the problem is?
I appreciate your answers!!

My try with valueBoxOutput, but with the same result:

**ui.R**

```
  body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    valueBoxOutput("totalSales")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("salesTable")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("top10Sales")
  )

)
```

**server.R**

```
function(input, output, session) {
  output$salesTable = DT::renderDataTable(top10Sales)
  output$top10Sales = DT::renderDataTable(top10Sales)
  #output$totalSales = DT::renderDataTable(totalSales)
  output$totalSales <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(totalSales, "Approval",color = "yellow")
    })

}
```

And still the same result:

[image: Output with <code>valueBoxOutput</code>]

By the way: Infobox is working:

```
infoBox("test", value=1, width=3)
```

Comment: try ValueBoxOutput? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/flexdashboard/versions/0.5.1/topics/valueBox-shiny

Comment: didnt help see my edit

Comment: You might have conflicting `id`s

Comment: @PorkChop what do you mean by conflicting id's?

Comment: Any webpage can only have elements with unique `id`, this means that if you have element with `id = totalSales` it might conflict if you're trying to assign another object with that name. I suggest you right click on webpage and click on `inspect element` and see the `console` in top right if there are any errors

Answer (score 0):

`valueBox` has to be used on the server side. To display a shiny dynamic UI element, there's generally a function (in this case `valueBoxOutput`) available to display it:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    valueBoxOutput("totalCars")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(header = dashboardHeader(),
                    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
                    body = body
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table = DT::renderDataTable(mtcars)

  output$totalCars <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox("Total", nrow(mtcars), color = "blue")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: it is server side. I separated in ui.R and server.R. See my edit above

Comment: this is what you use in your ui.R: `valueBox(totalSales,"Total Sales",color="blue")`. Change it to `valueBoxOutput("totalSales")`.

Comment: no I am using this please see again. I have one valueBox and valueBoxOutput. I did an edit few moments ago

Comment: Still seeing `valueBox(totalSales,"Total Sales",color="blue")` in your body after your edit. I'm telling you to get rid of this line.

Comment: Check my edit. If that does not work, I'd suggest you to put a reproducible example using `mtcars`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172431/discussion-between-stelios-and-kluu).